# MySQL Stored Procedure update using a Join and CASE..ELSE syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case

This is my first time creating a MySQL stored procedure and am stuck on getting the UPDATE piece to work correctly. The proc is performing an inner join, looking for matches on a domain name field. If there is a match, a column named `inbound` is getting updated with a value of 0. If there is not a match on the join, then I need `inbound` set to a value of 1. 
When I run this, I am able to get the matches tagged with a 0, but the non-matches are not getting updated with a 1. I thought how I have the 'ELSE' part set up would take care of this- can anyone tell if I am missing something with the syntax?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_InboungTagging`()

BEGIN

    update `tableA` a
         inner join `TableD` d
                  on a.senderDomain = d.domainName
                        set inbound = CASE 
                            when a.senderDomain = d.domainName then  0
                              ELSE 1

END

        WHERE inbound is null;

END;|

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks,

Ron

EDIT- 
Thanks for your reply. I am looking for exact matches on a varchar field that has domain names in it- the master list of domains is in table D. If the record in TableA has a match in TableD, I want to tag that recored with a 0. If there is no match in TableD, then I would like to tag it with a 1. Let me know if that clears things up- thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `JOIN` condition is the same as your `CASE` condition. If you `JOIN` your two tables on:

```
a.senderDomain = d.domainName
```

Then there will be no values in the result set for which

```
a.senderDomain != d.domainName
```

so the `ELSE` clause of your `CASE` statement never fires.

Without knowing more about what you mean by "matches" and "non-matches," I can't really suggest a correction.